# AWS Amplify: How to setup { withConnector } component?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

Following the [Amplify Quick Start](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/quick_start) I set up an AWS Mobile App with the `awsmobile-cli`:

```
awsmobile init
awsmobile user-signin enable
awsmobile push
```

In my react App I configured Amplify like so (I also tried manual configuration):

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from '../../aws-exports.js';
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';

...
export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

This Code shows me the **Cognito UI**, but on any action, I take the following error appears:

> > No userPool

**How do I properly connect the Amplify `withConnector` component with my App's userPool?**

---

P.S. Yesterday evening my app was working flawlessly. Today I only performed some minor changes and cannot explain this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if there is `aws-amplify` under your `node_modules/aws-amplify-react/node_modules`. Sometimes npm will install it twice and caused some problem

Comment: Could have been the problem. I deleted the npm folder and my aws mobile app and after a new setup everything seems working. I think I'll accept your answer to close this issue.